# Passing props to Material-UI HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a custom component that calls another custom component made using withStyles. It looks like this

```
import {FormControl, InputBase, InputLabel, withStyles} from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";

export const CustomInput = withStyles((theme) => ({
    ...
    }
}))(InputBase);

export const CustomTextField = (props) => {
  ...

  return (
        <FormControl fullWidth >
            <CustomInput
                id={id}
                fullWidth
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                value={value}
                variant={'outlined'}
                disabled={disabled}
                name={name}
                height={height}
                multiline={multiline}
                minRows={3} maxRows={10}
            />
        </FormControl>
  );
}
```

I'm getting an error `saying React does not recognize the "minRows" prop on a DOM element.` As well as "maxRows". But when I look at the `InputBase` API both minRows and maxRows are present. This is using v4 material UI

EDIT:
[DOM Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p8ff.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minRows` and `maxRows` are only valid when `multiline` is set to true:

https://mui.com/api/input-base/

What happens when multiline is set to false is all unknown/unused props are passed on to the underlying DOM element. Since minRows and maxRows are not valid DOM attributes, this explains the error you are getting. Make sure you only set min/max rows when multiline is actually true. I'm not in a place I can test this, but I believe you can do this:

```
minRows={multiline ? 3 : null}
maxRows={multiline ? 10 : null}
```

UPDATE: make sure you're on the latest version of MUI - you can do so by running `npm update` or `yarn upgrade`.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this but it did not seem to work. I even added a conditional to only add min and max rows to props if multiline is true and the issue persisted. Thanks for the input though

Comment: Can you look at the DOM and see what element it's being applied to? You should see `minRows` on some element in the dom. `document.querySelector('[minRows]')` should find the element from the browser dev tools console.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the original post of what the DOM looks like the props are being added to the InputBase-root which is a div. That is why it isn't working but I'm not sure of a solution for that.

Comment: I've recreated the code you've shown us, and it works as expected, so you must have something else going on. You can start with this working pen and add things one at a time until it more resembles your app - the error should reveal itself: https://codepen.io/DesignByOnyx/pen/zYdzZgx

Comment: Ok I finally got it, the issue wasn't in the code. Like you showed it works in your example. The issue was I was using version 4.11.4, I updated to 4.12.3 and it works correctly now. Thanks a lot for your help Ryan

Comment: Glad to hear. And the technique I used of creating a minimal example is very useful for both you and us as it helps strip away all the other stuff going on in your app and allows us to pinpoint exactly where the problem is. That's my go-to method for fixing these head-scratcher types of issues. It takes some time to get used to it, but it really helps you see your code for what it is.